# error when trying to use "Integer.parseInt(*) "

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

Here is my code:

```
void openContactsList() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // getting phone number and name of the contacts
    Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = new String[] {
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER };
    Cursor people = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null,
            null);
    int indexName = people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
    int indexNumber = people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
    j = 0;
    people.moveToFirst();
    ContactsDataBase entry = new ContactsDataBase(Contacts.this);
    entry.open();
    do {
        LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(this);
        row.setLayoutParams(params);
        for (j = 0; (j < 3) && next; j++) {
            // create the person and put it in the db table

            String name = people.getString(indexName);
            String number = people.getString(indexNumber);
            // create every person Image button
            CheckBox btnTag = new CheckBox(this);
            butparams.setMargins(j, 10, 0, 0);
            btnTag.setGravity(10);
            btnTag.setLayoutParams(butparams);
            btnTag.setText(number + "\n" + name);
            btnTag.setTextSize(10);
            btnTag.setTag("Button " + name);
            try {
                int num = Integer.parseInt(number);
                btnTag.setId(num);
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                // Handle parse error.
            }
            entry.createEntry(name, number, indexNumber);
            btnTag.getLayoutParams().width = 70;
            btnTag.getLayoutParams().height = 70;
            next = people.moveToNext();
            row.addView(btnTag);
        }
        layout12.addView(row);
    } while (next);
    entry.close();
    people.`enter code here`close();
}
```

I am having problem with getting numbers that are starting with `*` .
I think the problem is with `Integer.parseInt(number);` line.
When I am trying to take the Try and catch off I am getting an error.
So how can i get all the numbers without an exceptions.
Thanks.

Comment: can you show your logcat ..

Comment: 11-05 11:45:11.905: W/System.err(7619): java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '*5678' as integer
11-05 11:45:12.085: W/System.err(7619): java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '01318183970223' as integer

Comment: So as u see i think that the integer is a problem but im not quite sure about it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Integer.parseInt() wants the **string representation of a number**. A string with * **is not a number**.
As DavidFletcher said, remove all the unwanted characters (including + or spaces) to make your string a **clean number**.

Comment: But i need to keep the number as it is, emm i just need to make every Checkbox an id. if is it as your said i will use the row id as the id of the checkbox so i can call them when i want to.
but if there is another way to make this String with the * or spaces to a number so it will be better..

Comment: No, there isn't. *123456 **is not a number** and it will never be. You ould trick it replacing * with -. This will make it a **negative number**, which is a **valid integer**. So you can have, say -123456 as an integer id.

Comment: 11-05 11:45:12.085: W/System.err(7619): java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '01318183970223' as integer
1)what about this long number without spaces and *, is it because its too long? so i have to use long variables?
2) is that str.replace("*", "") replace all the * in the number to "" ? (even if its inside it)

Comment: This line executes correctly **System.out.println("" + Integer.parseInt("-1234567890"));** **The maximum int number is (2^31)-1, which is 2147483647**

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to retain the *? If not can't you replace * with ""

Answer (score 0):

Integer.parseInt(str) expects str to be an integer.

If you are using an EditBox as the source of input in your app, you can add this attribute to your xml and it will only allow numeric characters as imput:
    android:inputType="number"

Otherwise, you can remove the * character by doing Integer.parseInt(str.replace("*", "")).

Note that you can also use "numberDecimal" for decimal numbers.

Comment: what about the spaces and #?

Comment: If you have other characters, you can also replace those in the same way. Another thing to keep in mind (looking at the comment on your original post) is that the maximum size of an integer is 2147483647 so if you have numbers bigger than that, maybe you'll want to use a Long.

Comment: Remove everything which is not in the range -1234567890. This line executes correctly **System.out.println("" + Integer.parseInt("-1234567890"));**